# Inverse Fourier transform of complex exponential with frequency dependent shift

Tags: fourier-transform

In the case of a constant delay $\tau$, we have the following equality:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{F^{-1}}\left\{e^{-j\omega \tau}\right\}=\delta(t-\tau)\end{align}$$

If the delay is frequency dependent $\tau(\omega)$, can ${F^{-1}}\left\{e^{-j\omega \tau(f)}\right\}$ be expressed as a sum of diracs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case: no.

For the (inverse) Fourier transform of a function to be composed of a sum of countable diracs (i.e. to be discrete), the function needs to be periodic.

Your $e^{-j\omega\tau(f)}$ is not periodic (it *can* be periodic, if $\omega\tau(f)$ happen to be periodic with period rationally related to $2\pi$, but that's a pretty special case). Therefore, its inverse Fourier transform is continuous, and can't be represented by a sum of diracs.